# HTML dialog - background colour

Tags: css, html, dialog, modal-dialog

I have been following a couple of guides of how to create a dialog box:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/a-preview-of-the-new-dialog-element

For some reason, my CSS is not rendering the background-colour.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8kRc3/

HTML:

```
<dialog class="modal">This is the dialog!</dialog>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
    /* arbitrary styling */
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    /* change position to fixed if you want to prevent the dialog from scrolling away, and center it */
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
.modal::backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: You ask the CSS to apply white background on the .modal... when the background is white... white on white dude...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the background color to any other color then white ! it's working in Chrome : take a look here ... 
http://jsfiddle.net/8kRc3/3/

```
body{
     background-color: blue;
}
.modal {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i mean background-colour around the dialoag.

Answer (score 4):

State 2023: there is the `::backdrop` CSS pseudo element.

```
dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

For more info, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop?retiredLocale=en

Answer (score 2):

please try in this way

```
 .modal::after {
        position: fixed;
        content:'';
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, it only works if you call the method `.showModal()`

The ::backdrop CSS pseudo-element can be used to style behind a  element when the dialog is displayed with `HTMLDialogElement.showModal()`. For example, to dim unreachable content behind the modal dialog.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the:

background: color;

Instead of the background-color which doesn't work.